Why the Grid children objects RowParent_0 and RowParent_9 don't have any children?
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridCellPrefab;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;

    private GameObject[] wallParents = new GameObject[4];
    private GameObject gridContainer;
    private GameObject[] rowParents; // Parents for each row of grid cells

    void Start()
    {
        CreateGridContainer();
        GenerateGrid();
    }

    void CreateGridContainer()
    {
        gridContainer = GameObject.Find("GridContainer");
        if (gridContainer == null)
        {
            gridContainer = new GameObject("GridContainer");
            gridContainer.transform.parent = this.transform;
        }

        // Initialize wall parent objects
        string[] wallNames = { "TopWallParent", "LeftWallParent", "RightWallParent", "BottomWallParent" };
        for (int i = 0; i < wallParents.Length; i++)
        {
            wallParents[i] = new GameObject(wallNames[i]);
            wallParents[i].transform.parent = gridContainer.transform;
        }

        // Initialize row parent objects
        rowParents = new GameObject[gridHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < gridHeight; i++)
        {
            rowParents[i] = new GameObject("RowParent_" + i);
            rowParents[i].transform.parent = gridContainer.transform;
        }
    }

    public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        // Clear previous grid
        foreach (Transform child in gridContainer.transform)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
        CreateGridContainer(); // Recreate wall and row parents

        // Generate new grid
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject cell = Instantiate(gridCellPrefab, new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f), Quaternion.identity);
                cell.name = "GridCell_" + x + "_" + z;
                cell.tag = "GridCell";
                cell.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0.945f, 1f, 0f);

                // Adjust parent based on position
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    cell.transform.parent = wallParents[0].transform;
                    cell.name = "TopWallCell_" + z;
                }
                else if (z == 0)
                {
                    cell.transform.parent = wallParents[1].transform;
                    cell.name = "LeftWallCell_" + x;
                }
                else if (z == gridHeight - 1)
                {
                    cell.transform.parent = wallParents[2].transform;
                    cell.name = "RightWallCell_" + x;
                }
                else if (x == gridWidth - 1)
                {
                    cell.transform.parent = wallParents[3].transform;
                    cell.name = "BottomWallCell_" + z;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.transform.parent = rowParents[z].transform;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

this is how the grid structure looks like in the hierarchy:

is that logic and supposed to be like this where RowParent_0 and RowParent_9 don't have any children?
there are no errors or problems with the grid,  i just wonder why the first and last don't have any children.

Would suspect that they fall into one of your other if cases.
→ they get parented somewhere else? In particular z == 0 and z == gridHeight - 1 for instance
You will note that also the ones for x == 0 and x == gridWidth - 1 are not under the z row parents either
